# apex select2 plugin not work well with oracle apex 20.1

Tags: css, styles, oracle-apex, multi-select, oracle-apex-20.1

Need to add a multi select item into my oracle apex form. Tried to use apex [select2 plugin.](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=64237:20) But it didn't work well. When I add into the form it looks like in the below image,

[image]

Then I tried to change the styles when page load with js. But I cannot access inner components of the select2 item. Are there any other plugins like this..? How do I use this component in my apex application.? any suggestions..?

Comment: Did you try to contact plug-in author(s)?

Comment: no dear. i didnt...

Comment: Your title says `apex 21.1`, but your tags say `apex 19.2` - which one are you using? Is there even a 2021 version yet? Note that `19.2` introduces a much improved `Popup LOV` item type, that supports multi select amongst other cool features. I did use `select2` in the past, but switched to the built in item type recently.

Comment: @ThomasTschernich Thanks dear. My bad. It should be 20.1. I selected 19.2 because there is no tag for 20.1 yet. So I selected the closest one.. :)

Comment: `oracle-apex-20.1` Tag created and added

Answer (score 2):

This is for apex 20.2. I added this css and it looks better. Maybe it will help others.

```
.select2-selection {position: relative;}
.select2-container {border: none; padding: 0;}
.select2-container .select2-selection--single
.select2-selection__clear {font-size: 14px; color: #888889; line-height: 28px;}
input.select2-search__field {outline-offset: 0;}
.t-Form-fieldContainer--floatingLabel.plugin-be\.ctb\.select2 .t-Form-labelContainer .t-Form-label {top: -1.2rem; font-size: 1.1rem}
.t-Form-fieldContainer--floatingLabel.plugin-be\.ctb\.select2 .apex-item-select.select2.select2-container {border-radius: 2px; border: 0.1rem solid #dfdfdf; padding-right: 8px !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Select2 plugin with the Universal Theme, but the current version does not work well with the **"Optional - Floating"** / **"Required - Floating"** item templates.

I always use either the **"Optional"** / **"Required"** templates (with the label shown to the left of the item) or the **"Optional - Above"** / **"Required - Above"** templates.

Also, I always find I need to set the **Width** plugin attribute to get it to look ok.